# How can I generate a bitcoin address?

Tags: blockchain, wallet, api, address-generation

Is there any way to generate bitcoin addresses  other than the Blockchain API? (given the fact that it is not public)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a long and detailed tutorial on it http://procbits.com/2013/08/27/generating-a-bitcoin-address-with-javascript

In short, scroll all the way down to the summary to see this short version:

```
var randArr = new Uint8Array(32) //create a typed array of 32 bytes (256 bits)
window.crypto.getRandomValues(randArr) //populate array with cryptographically secure random numbers

//some Bitcoin and Crypto methods don't like Uint8Array for input. They expect regular JS arrays.
var privateKeyBytes = []
for (var i = 0; i < randArr.length; ++i)
  privateKeyBytes[i] = randArr[i]

var eckey = new Bitcoin.ECKey(privateKeyBytes)
eckey.compressed = true
var address = eckey.getBitcoinAddress().toString()
console.log(address)// 1FkKMsKNJqWSDvTvETqcCeHcUQQ64kSC6s

var privateKeyBytesCompressed = privateKeyBytes.slice(0) //clone array
privateKeyBytesCompressed.push(0x01)
var privateKeyWIFCompressed = new Bitcoin.Address(privateKeyBytesCompressed)
privateKeyWIFCompressed.version = 0x80
privateKeyWIFCompressed = privateKeyWIFCompressed.toString()
```

Open up the JavaScript console on the page (in your browser) and follow along. You can create your very own address right there in the browser. I wouldn't recommend using this newly created address to actually conduct commerce. Just use it as an academic exercise.

Comment: `I wouldn't recommend using this newly created address to actually conduct commerce. Just use it as an academic exercise.` Why do you say that? Are there any risks associated with this method (as I intend to use it for generating personal cold-storage keys)

Comment: Yes, generating a private key in the browser where other scripts/plugins may have access to the keys puts your money at risk.

Comment: Gotcha, but I can use my own personal Javascript IDE or something just fine. Just wanted to make sure there wasn't a potential risk with the code itself (as opposed to the environment) Thanks for clarification

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of sample programs here: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1026.0

Also see the wiki for the [step-by-step algorithm for generating a valid address.](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_Bitcoin_addresses)

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of very easy-to-use tools that can generate addresses for you, the exact process is detailed [in the Bitcoin wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_Bitcoin_addresses).

Some examples of such tools are:

- [BitAddress.org](https://www.bitaddress.org/)
- [BrainWallet](http://brainwallet.org)

Answer (score -3):

[Coinbase](https://coinbase.com/) Your wallet on Coinbase is a collection of bitcoin addresses. New bitcoin addresses are automatically generated for each payment on Coinbase and stay associated with your account forever (so it is safe to reuse them).

Comment: I meant programatically, that's why I mentioned the blockchain API. And here you are giving me your "referral" link to coinbase.